# cURL не отображает кириллицу

Tags: php, curl, кириллица

Получаю с помощью cURL страницу, а она в ответ выводит вот такой `html` код(см. картинку. Как это можно исправить и выводить русский текст?
На сайте, с которого буду парсить, такая кодировка `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">`

Код:

```php
$post = [
    'name'=>'myname',
      'login'=>'melogin',
];
 
$ch = curl_init('http://site.com');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
 
$response = curl_exec($ch);
 
curl_close($ch);
 
// выводим результат
var_dump($response);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения])

Comment: Может `mb_internal_encoding("windows-1251"); mb_http_output( "windows-1251" );` ?

Comment: @Brave_Lime, к сожалению, нет

Answer (score 2):

Все, ответ найден, если кому-то нужно будет, то нужно вывести результат такой строчкой

```
echo iconv("windows-1251","utf-8", $response );
```